# Nodemailer not working with local smtp server

Tags: nodejs, mail-server

I have setup local smtp server in my linux machine.
The following command works and successfully received mail from test@<machine-name>.

```
echo “THIS IS A TEST EMAIL” | mail -s "This is subject" xxxx@gmail.com
```

Whereas I need to send mail using `nodemailer` which I have configured as below,

```
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host:"smtp.<ourserver>.com",
        secure:false
    });
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'test@<machine-name>', // sender address
        to: 'xxxx@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: "Hello", // Subject line
        html: "<i>Hello world</i>" // html body
    });
```

But I am getting the following error,

[image]

Any idea why I am facing this issue?

I have seen similar questions posted in quora but none of them solved my problem.

With [emailjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs), it works with the following config,

```
  const { SMTPClient } = require('emailjs');
  const client = new SMTPClient({
       host: 'smtp.<ourserver>.com',
       ssl: false,
       tls: false
  });
  client.send(
    {
       text: 'Hello',
       from: 'test@<machine-name>',
       to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
       subject: 'Hello',
    },
    (err, message) => {
         //
    }
 );
```

How can I make it work using `nodemailer`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the code to listen to the echo, then:

```
const auth = {
user: "email@email.com",
pass: "password"
};

const transporter = require('nodemailer').createTransport({
host: "smtp.<ourserver>.com",
port: 587,
auth
});


transporter.verify(function (error, _) {
    console.error(error);
}

const data = {
        to: "<to@email.com>,
        from: 'User Name <' + auth.user + '>',
        date: "<date>",
        subject: "Subject"
    };
transporter.sendMail(data, (response) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the nodemailer app may solve this problem. While installing the app, it automatically makes some settings in the background.
To install the application, simply install the snapcraft package and type  `sudo snap install nodemailerapp`